# Error on Wikipedia: Nelson's proof of Liouville's theorem works only for bounded modulus?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, potential-theory

On Wikipedia, it is stated:

> If $f$ is a harmonic function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which
>   is bounded above or bounded below, then $f$ is constant...Edward
>   Nelson gave a particularly short proof of this theorem, using the mean
>   value property mentioned above:
>
> *Given two points, choose two balls with the given points as centers and of equal radius. If the radius is large enough, the two balls will
>   coincide except for an arbitrarily small proportion of their volume.
>   Since f is bounded, the averages of it over the two balls are
>   arbitrarily close, and so f assumes the same value at any two points.*

But this is an error, right? Because Nelson's proof works if the harmonic function is bounded in *modulus*, not just bounded above or below. What is a simple way to exetend the proof to the case that the function is bounded above or below?

If such doesn't exist, where can I find a different proof of this fact?

I guess one way (for $n=2$) might be to invoke complex analysis, create $f$ entire such that $\text{Re}(f)$ is our harmonic function, and then reason about $e^{f}$.

Comment: You cannot use complex analysis for $n \neq 2$...

Comment: @StevenGubkin Thank you, I meant to mention that...

Comment: I think wikipedia is just wrong here.  Nelson's original proof just says "bounded", and I assume he means bounded in modulus.

Comment: Looking back at old notes, the only way I ever remember proving the stronger statement (bounded on one side) is through Harnack's inequality.  I will try to come up with a more conceptual proof.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are correct that the Wikipedia article's explanation only really works when $f$ is bounded in modulus; however, a slight change adapts the proof to the case when $f$ is bounded below or above only. The proof below can be found on page 45 of *Harmonic Function Theory* by Axler et al., for instance. I give another solution at the bottom that works when the dimension is equal to $2$.

Suppose $f$ is harmonic on $\mathbb R^n$ and bounded above or below. By replacing $f$ with $-f$ if necessary, we can assume that $f$ is bounded below, and then by adding a suitable constant we can assume that $f\geq 0$. It is clear that $|f(x) - f(y)|$ is bounded by the integral of $f$ over the symmetric difference of the balls $B(x,r)$ and $B(y,r)$ divided by the volume of a ball of radius $r$. But because $f$ is nonnegative, the integral of $f$ over the symmetric difference of $B(x,r)$ and $B(y,r)$ is bounded by the integral of $f$ over the annulus $B(x,r+|x-y|)\setminus B(x,r-|x-y|)$ (this is easiest to see if you draw a picture). Thus
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(y)| & \leq {1\over|B(0,r)|}\int_{B(x,r+|x-y|)\setminus B(y,r-|x-y|)}f\\
 &= {1\over |B(0,r)|}\int_{B(x,r+|x-y|)}f - {1\over |B(0,r)|}\int_{B(x,r-|x-y|)}f \\[0.2em]
& = {(r+|x-y|)^n - (r-|x-y|)^n\over r^n}f(x).
\end{align*}
The expression above is $O(r^{-1})$, so making $r\to\infty$ gives $f(x) = f(y)$.

---

Here's another proof for dimension $n=2$. Again suppose $f\geq0$ is harmonic. For $\epsilon>0$, put $f_\epsilon(z) = f(z) + \epsilon\log{|z|}$. Let $m = \inf{f}$. Now $f_\epsilon$ is harmonic on $|z|> 1$ and continuous on the boundary $|z| = 1$. Moreover, since $f\geq 0$, we know that $f_\epsilon(z)\geq \epsilon\log{|z|} \to\infty$ with $|z|$. Thus for all $\epsilon>0$, the maximum principle tells us that $\inf{f_\epsilon}$ is attained on the unit circle $|z|=1$. Since $\log{|z|} = 0$ on the circle, it follows that this infimum is independent of $\epsilon$; call it $k$, and note that $k>m$ because $f$ attains the value $k$ somewhere on the unit circle, while $f$ cannot attain $m$ anywhere on the plane by the maximum principle. Then for each $z$ with $|z|\geq 1$, we have $f_\epsilon(z)\geq k >m$ for all $\epsilon$. It follows by making $\epsilon\to0$ that $f(z) \geq k$. But if $f(z)\geq k$ whenever $|z|\geq1$, then $f(z)\geq k$ for $|z| < 1$ as well by the maximum principle. But now we have found that $f(z)\geq k>m$ for all $z$, contradicting the definition of $m$ as the infimum of $f$.

Comment: +1 The second proof actually uses only the minimum principle for $f$; thus, it applies to all superharmonic functions $f$. Which  explains why its applicability is restricted to $n=2$: in higher dimensions there are positive superharmonic functions on $\mathbb R^n$.